# What’s the best way to parallelize this?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, opencl

I have a file which is composed of some 800 000 lines. Each line is formed by an id, a code and data, each field separated by a TAB.

```
3445    aaaa    Some data here for instance
89002   aree    Some other data
```

As a pure exercise to get acquainted with OpenCL, I decided to parse this file using OpenCL. Each work item goes through one single line and processes it. Each line is 4000-character long.

```
__kernel void parse_line(
            __global const char * lines,   // IN
            __global unsigned * id,        // OUT
            __global char * code,          // OUT
            __global char * data           // OUT
        )
{
   // parse the line to extract id, code and data
}
```

Given that `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` is 1024, I can’t have more than 1024 work items at the same time. I can’t either pump the entire file into the GPU memory (`CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE` is only 268353536).

A first idea could be to parse a first batch of 1024 sentences, then a second one, and so on, keeping the kernel with the task to treat one single sentence. I could also rewrite the kernel so that instead of parsing one sentence it parses 16, then the 1024 work items would treat some 16384 sentences.

I am pretty new to OpenCL as mentioned earlier, so I am really looking for advises on how to best do that.

Comment: Rewriting a kernel to parse 16 sentences instead of 1 is very similar to "loop unrolling." Anyhow, you need to determine what your bandwidth to your GPU is. Consider that you're using your CPU like a "cache" for your GPU in this case, and optimize accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCL wouldn't have been my first choice for text processing.  Though, there is probably some set of problems for which it makes sense.  Can you decompose the entire algorithm into steps and see what the bottleneck is (are you going to do anything with the data after parsing the file?)?  Moving those strings over various buses to be reduced later is likely suboptimal.  Reduce them at the earliest opportunity.  It looks like you're not even reducing them, just splitting the stream, but keeping the data as character strings?

If indeed parsing and converting the values is the bottleneck, then I would recommend continuing your experiment of breaking down the large file into blocks which can fit into memory.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is helping. You are right, I could just return pointers, or offsets, so that the host knows where to split the lines.
Now for the bottlenecks. Do you know any way to measure the gpu code ? (something like `gprof`?)

Comment: Do you have a baseline implementation for this algorithm, or are you implementing it for the first time in OCL?

Answer (score 1):

Is the bottleneck the reading of the file or the parsing? If it's the reading then there is not much you can besides storing the file on a faster medium. If it's the parsing, you could read the whole file into an array or `std::vector` then use threads, where each thread is parsing a part of the array/vector.

Comment: I might not have explained the problem clearly, but I totally am in the second situation, and my problem is to optimize the parsing process. I won’t use threads because I am not using the CPU to parse the file, but the GPU, thanks to OpenCL.

Comment: @qdii Is there a requirement that you must use the GPU/OpenCL? A modern GPU is extremely good at doing lots of things in parallel, but not really suited for text-parsing.

Comment: I can see that :/ but this is a pure exercise to get acquainted with OpenCL. I am doing it to learn how OpenCL works.

Comment: @qdii Ah okay. Good luck then! :)